# Flutter Drawer gets rebuilt everytime i open it

Tags: flutter

I have been workign on this hours trying to solve why the drawer getting rebuilt everytime i open it. Without any progress, i came here to seek for guidance how can i load it once and rebuild it when i need to?

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home")),
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}


class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Build");
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text("Lisa Simpsons"),
            accountEmail: Text("lisa.simpsons@thesimpsons.com"),
          ),
          Text("Grade A - Student")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with rebuilding `MyDrawer` when you open it?

Comment: For example if i have `Futurebuild` inside my `Drawer`. Thats getting rebuilt everytime aswell. Which i don't need it to, even if i fetch the data through the `initState`. Which cause not a pleasent user experience, you have to wait for same data getting rebuilt.

Comment: I've already done that, But i suspect since the `drawer` getting rebuilt. Then the data is also loading again

Comment: hmmm, tried `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`?

Comment: Yes, with no luck. Still getting rebuilt, even tho i use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on another widget. Which works wonders

Comment: so it seems that they did it on purpose and you need some `Provider` / `Bloc` / `ScopedModel` stuff ...

Comment: How would i go about it with `Provider` since i use it on my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Widget inside `drawer:` will always be rebuilt because it is disposed when it is closed. You can just perform a simple checking what widget to return based from its state.

In this example, if state is still `null` it will fetch the data using `FutureBuilder`. When it is already fetched, it will directly return the `Drawer` widget.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String grade; // Sample state

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
      drawer: Builder(
        builder: (_) {
          if (grade != null) {
            return MyDrawer(grade);
          }

          return FutureBuilder<String>(
            future: Future<String>.delayed(
              const Duration(seconds: 5),
              () => grade = 'A+',
            ),
            builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              print('>>>>>>> snapshot = ${snapshot.data}');
              return MyDrawer(snapshot.data);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer(this.grade);

  final String grade;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Build');

    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text('Lisa Simpsons'),
            accountEmail: Text('lisa.simpsons@thesimpsons.com'),
          ),
          Text('Grade A - Student${grade == null ? "" : "  >>>>>> ($grade)"}')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Update: Sample using `provider`.

```
class SampleState extends ChangeNotifier {
  SampleState() {
    fetchGrade();
  }

  String _grade;

  String get grade => _grade;

  Future<void> fetchGrade() async {
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> FETCHING GRADE');
    await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    _grade = 'A+';
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<SampleState>(
      create: (_) => SampleState(),
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Build');

    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text('Lisa Simpsons'),
            accountEmail: Text('lisa.simpsons@thesimpsons.com'),
          ),
          Consumer<SampleState>(
            builder: (_, SampleState state, __) {
              print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> REBUILD');
              final String append =
                  state.grade == null ? '' : '  >>>>>>>>>> (${state.grade})';

              return Text('Grade A - Student$append');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but seems bit kindy hacky way to do it, in my opinion. I hope i'm wrong

Comment: @Printer Yes, it's kindda hacky. But if you have a state management plugin, like `provider`, that code would be much cleaner and does not look hacky.

Comment: Well i have `provider`, any example how i can achive it with `provider`

Comment: @Printer Added sample using provider.